# Simplifying the contraction of the riemannian curvature tensor with a timelike projection matrix

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

I'm reading this short piece ["Physical and Geometric Interpretations of the Riemann Tensor, Ricci Tensor,and Scalar Curvature"](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401099) ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0401099.pdf)), and I'm having trouble grasping one the simplifications used in Section 7. Specifically, Equation 9 on page 9.

To give context, the author wants to compute the scalar curvature in "the D − 1 subspace that is orthogonal to a particular [timelike] vector" $t^\mu$. To do this, they contract the Riemannian curvature tensor with what I assume to be the (inverse) metric induced on that D-1 dimensional space:
$$ (g^{-1}_{D-1})^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu} - t^\mu t^\nu \implies R_{D-1} = (g^{\mu\nu} - t^\mu t^\nu)(g^{\alpha\beta} - t^\alpha t^\beta) R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}$$

This is simplified in Equation 9 to obtain a contraction with the Einstein tensor. However, I don't know how this simplification is made. I assume the author first expanded

$$(g^{\mu\nu} - t^\mu t^\nu)(g^{\alpha\beta} - t^\alpha t^\beta) R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} = (g^{\mu\nu}g^{\alpha\beta}-2g^{\alpha\beta}t^\mu t^\nu + t^\mu t^\nu t^\alpha t^\beta)R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}$$

And then contracted
$$g^{\mu\nu}g^{\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} -2g^{\alpha\beta}t^\mu t^\nu R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} + t^\mu t^\nu t^\alpha t^\beta R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} = R - 2R_{\mu\nu}t^\nu t^\nu + t^\mu t^\nu t^\alpha t^\beta R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}$$

The third term is missing in the derivation without a justification. I don't see the symmetry of the projection matrix implying the simplification for simple algebraic reasons, as the metric tensor is also symmetric. If there's anything that I'm missing, nuanced or obvious, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} \ne R_{\mu\alpha , \nu\beta}$ See equation 9 again where the tensor contains derivatives.

Comment: I took that as a typo. Earlier on the page the author says "We would have to contract the Riemann tensor, not with $g^{\mu\nu}$, but rather with the projector onto our D−1 space". Plus, in Equation 9  they end up with the Ricci tensor and the Ricci scalar, and that makes sense to me only when the comma is a mistake and the author meant to have the fully lowered Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: Typo’s are always a possibility. I’ll try and have a read of whole article later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to the problem, and I found a solution that seems fairly straightforward. Rewriting the last contraction as $$ t^\mu t^\nu t^\alpha t^\beta R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} = \langle R(t,t)t,t\rangle$$
makes it clear that it must vanish, from the anti-symmetry of the curvature tensor.

A rearrangement of the contraction such as
$$ t^\mu t^\nu t^\alpha t^\beta R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} =  (t^\mu  t^\alpha) (t^\nu t^\beta) R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}$$
would also lead to the same conclusion.